# The pronunciation of the voiced "th" in English

Tags: english, phonology, dental-fricative

I speak General American English, and I pronounce voiced "th"'s in two different ways. The first, which is how I pronounce it in "the" and "father," feels somewhat like a stop; part of my tongue touches the roof of my mouth. The second way, which is how I pronounce it in "worthy" feels more like a "true" voiced dental fricative. Is this just an idiosyncrasy of mine?

Comment: It's well-known that some allophones of /ð/ can be plosives, affricates or something similar (see "[The stop-like modification of /ð/: A case study in the analysis and handling of speech variation](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/42205#files-area)", by Sherry Y. Zhao (2007) ), but I haven't heard before of people noticing that they consistently use a stop-like allophone more often in the word "father" than in the word "worthy". Zhao says that the stop-like allophone seems to be most common when /ð/ follows a plosive, which suggests it can be the result of some kind of assimilation.

Comment: It's quite credible because of the retraction and tongue-bunching of ɹ in GAE: this would constrain a change of ð to d̪. So compare Zhao's findings and tell us more about where this happens.

Comment: @sumelic That seems like a good answer in and of itself